# Can't seem to make the email and name field editable using php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm very new to PHP and don't use it very often and have come across a bit of a problem I was wondering someone might know the answer to.

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/contact.php

The link above displays my problem where I can't seem to edit and type into the white space for email and name but the message textarea seems to be fine. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the php that has been written or the css.

If anyone can see anything else wrong i would greatly appreciate that as like I said I'm new to the whole concept of PHP.

Thanks

Comment: On a side note, I'd change the `<p>` tags to `<div>` tags. It's an overall neater approach as `<p>` elements should only really have text and images in.

Comment: FWIW, in design terms there's probably too many colour changes in your _If your looking for a Front End Web Developer_... paragraph; excessive colour changes work a bit like excessive emboldening, and make text a bit harder to read. The re-coloured phrase _get in touch_ looks like it should be a hyperlink, but isn't. HTH!

Comment: Thanks Halfer will make those changes, what does FWIW mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the CSS, remove the `position:relative;` from this section:

```
#popup #MessageSubmit {
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Cool Thank you. Any chance you could explain why it did that please? Just so I understand why. Thanks